# Error Separating Multiple Rules in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr

I've almost finished my first adventure with ANTLR, and it's been quite a trip. Unfortunately, always only counts in horseshoes, hand grenades, and nuclear weapons, right?

Anyways, I'm trying to parse an input that looks like this:

```
; IF AGE IS LESS THAN 21, STILL RETURN TRUE FOR OVERSEAS LOCATION \r\n
SHOW "AGE REQUIREMENTS FAILED" FOR \r\n
IF AGE < 21 THEN \r\n
LOCATION = "OVERSEAS" \r\n
ENDIF \r\n
\r\n
; NEED  SOMEONE WHO HAS WORKED FOR US FOR > 1 YEAR EXCEPT FOR CEO \r\n
SHOW "MINIMUM TIME REQUIREMENT NOT MET" FOR \r\n
IF STARTDATE > TODAY - 1 YEAR THEN \r\n
EMPLID=001 \r\n
ENDIF \r\n
```

Generally, if the test fails, the message is shown.

Anyways, a set can contain 1 or more SHOW rules. Processing of a single SHOW rule works, but it won't "split" when an inputstream contains > 1 SHOW rules.

Here are the relevant rules from the grammar:

```
showGroup returns [List<PolicyEvaluation> value]
  @init {List<PolicyEvaluation> peList = new ArrayList<PolicyEvaluation>();}
  : (expr1=show)* {peList.add($expr1.value);}
  {
    System.out.println("Entered policyGroup rule");
    $value = peList;
  }
  ;

// evaluate a single SHOW statement
show returns [PolicyEvaluation value]
  : ('SHOW' expr1=STRING 'FOR')? expr2=ifStatement EOL*
  {
    System.out.println("Entered show rule");
    Boolean expr2Value = (Boolean) $expr2.value;
    PolicyEvaluation pe = new PolicyEvaluation();
    if (expr1 == null) {
      pe.setValue(expr2Value);
      pe.setMessage(null);
    } else {
        if (expr2Value == false) {
          pe.setValue(false);
          pe.setMessage(expr1.getText());
        } else {
          pe.setValue(true);
          pe.setMessage(null);
        }   
    }
    $value = pe;
  }
  ;
// rules leading up to the show rule
// domain-specific grammar rules
STRING: '"' ID  (' ' ID)* '"'
  {
    System.out.println("Entered STRING lexer rule");
    // strip the quotes once we match this token
    setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1));
  }
  ;
COMMENT: ';' (ID|' ')* EOL {$channel = HIDDEN;};
EOL: ('\r'|'\n'|'\r\n') {$channel = HIDDEN;};
SPACE: ' ' {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Maybe this is something simple. Any help is appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this: `(expr1=show)* {peList.add($expr1.value);}`

to this: `(expr1=show {peList.add($expr1.value);})*`

The action as it is will only fire after all `show` matches have completed, leaving you to operate on the last `expr1`.